# Well behaved colon between powers of ideals when the associated graded ring is Cohen-Macaulay.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, cohen-macaulay

I'm reading a paper: A formula for the core of an ideal, by Claudia Polini and Bernd Ulrich and I'm in trouble with the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ with $\mathrm{ht}(I)>0$. If $\mathrm {gr}_I(R)$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then $I^{m+n}:_RI^n = I^m$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Well, I only proved this result with the following additional hypothesis: "R Cohen-Macaulay local ring with infinite residue field", because I was able to use some classical theorems that allowed me to find a homogeneous $\mathrm{gr}_I(R)$-regular element of degree 1.

Can someone help me in this problem?

In the article: Reductions Numbers and Balanced Ideals, by Louiza Fouli, this result is apparently used at the end of proposition 2.1. She says the cancellation law is clear, because $grade(gr_I(R)_+)>0$, since $gr_I(R)$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $ht(I)>0$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The paper is: A formula for the core of an ideal, by Claudia Polini and Bernd  Ulrich. I didn't mention the name of the paper because this fact isn't a result in this paper. This fact is only used in this paper.  It is used, for example, in the end of the page 3.

Comment: It is not clear to me: you want $R$ to be non-local and/or remove the constraint "with infinite residue field"?

Comment: I don't know if the local hipothesis is in fact necessary, but I want to remove the condition: " With infinite residual field".  In other words, if you solve the case Cohen-Macaulay local, you solve my problem.

Comment: In the article: Reductions Numbers and Balanced Ideals, by Louiza Fouli, this result is used at the end of proposition 2.1. She said the cancellation law is clear, because grade(gr_I(R)_+)>0, since gr_I(R) is Cohen-Macaulay and ht(I)>0.

Comment: At first glance I think you really need a regular element of degree one in the associated graded ring, and it is provided by assuming that the residue field is infinite. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Exactly, I used the the assumption about infinite residue field to give me a homogeneous regular element of degree 1 in gr_I(R). The problem is that this result is valid when k isn't infinite. Parallelly I'm going to try to follow the advice of my advisor. He suggested me to change the ring in order the new residue field be infinite.

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. But I wonder why Huneke and Swanson in their *Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules*, Lemma 8.5.8, did not mention this?

Comment: Yes, I saw. Maybe there is something deep in the proof of this result. I just think the paper article should indicate some reference for the proof this result.  Talking with the comunity, It seems clear that it isn't trivial.

Comment: Btw, the usual procedure to obtain a local ring with infinite residue field from a given local ring $R$ is to consider $S=R[X]_{\mathfrak m[X]}$. I hope this can help you. (Unfortunately I don't have time to check whether all conditions are still satisfied when replace $R$ by $S$.)

Comment: Yes, this exactly the ring change my advisor suggested me. Thank you, user26857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G = gr_I(R)$ and $G_n$ denote the n-th graded piece $I^n/I^{n+1}$ of $G$. We will show that if the grade of $G_+$ is positive, then $I^{n+i} : I^n = I^i$.

For $l > 0$, we will use the following.

> (1) For any non-zero element $Z \in G_n$, there exists a lift $z \in I^n \setminus I^{n+1}$ of $Z$. That is $Z = z + I^{n+1} \in I^n/I^{n+1} = G_n$. 
>  
>   (2) If $Z \in G_l$ is a nonzerodivisor and $z \in I^l \setminus I^{l+1}$ is a lift of $Z$, then $I^{n+l}:z = I^n$ for $n > l$. 
>   (3) If grade $G_+ > 0$, then there exists a homogeneous nonzerodivor in $G_+$. 
>   (4) For any $m \ge n$, $I^{n+i} : I^n \subset I^{m+i} : I^m$.

In any case, $I^i \subset I^{n+i}:I^n$. Let $y \in I^{n+i}:I^n$. Let $Z \in G_l$ be a nonzerodivisor and $z$ a lift of $Z$ in $I^l$. Choose $m$ such that $m \ge n$ and $l \mid m$. Then $y \in I^{m+i}:I^m$ and
$$
yz^{m/l} \subset yI^m \subset I^{m+i}.
$$
Thus, $y \in I^{m+i}:z^{m/l} = I^i$.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very clever, youngsu. However, I have an doubt: is the case $l=0$ trivial?

Comment: I imagine that in the proof that grade(G_+)>0, it's possible to find a non-zerodivisor homogeneous element of degree positive. I'm looking for the proof.

Comment: Please take a look at the graded version of prime avoidance in https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma. Use $G_+$ for $J$ and the associated primes of $G$ for those $I_i$'s. Since $G$ is graded, these associated primes are graded too.

Comment: Thanks, youngsu. Actually, my doubt doesn't make sense, because G_0\cap(G_+)=0, so if Z is homogeneous G-regular element in G_+, it necessary true that $Z \in G_l$ for some $l>0$.